# Snowflake Manual Refresh Slowness

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema, snowflake-connector

I am refreshing the external table but it is taking quite long time...almost taking 7-8 hours in getting statement execution complete....any way to get rid of it ?

ALTER TABLE EXTERNAL_TABLE_NAME REFRESH

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a relative path to the refresh command.
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/alter-external-table.html

Answer (score 0):

The External table refresh times are also dependent on the number of files that are present in the stage. If this is a new table that was created, please try to refresh in parts by using the subpaths in the stage.

Also, check for values of the parameters REFRESH_ON_CREATE.

Comment: As I am new to Snowflake can you please help me how to check the REFRESH_ON_CREATE parameter ?

Comment: Below is the ddl I have of the table for which we are getting issue :

create or replace external table xxxxx(
 xxx VARCHAR(16777216) AS (SPLIT_PART(SPLIT_PART(METADATA$FILENAME, '/', 6), '=', 2)),
 xxx VARCHAR(16777216) AS (SPLIT_PART(METADATA$FILENAME, '/', 7)),
 PARTITIONDATE DATE AS (TO_DATE(SPLIT_PART(SPLIT_PART(METADATA$FILENAME, '/', 8), '=', 2), 'YYYYMMDD')))
partition by (PORTALCD, PARTITIONDATE)
location=@BLOBSTAGE_SEGMENT_PROD/
auto_refresh=false
file_format=(TYPE=parquet NULL_IF=())
;